Jenkins pipeline using sbt docker image | -u sbtuser causes job to get stuck
I am trying to create a Jenkins pipeline to build a sbt project. Currently, I am trying to use docker-sbt to run one sbt test stage.
The github project tells me to use sbtuser to run container as non-root user. But when I try to change user using -u sbtuser in container args it gets stuck.
Moreover -u root --privileged arg is working for me, but I don't know if it will cause issue with permissions on my Jenkins worker node.
Dockerfile ->
FROM sbtscala/scala-sbt:eclipse-temurin-17.0.4_1.7.1_3.2.0
WORKDIR /build

Pipeline ->
stage("1"){
  steps{
    script{
      docker.build(SBT_IMAGE_TAG, "./build-release-tools/Jenkins/MultiBranchJob/jdk17-sbt")
    }
  }
}
stage("2"){
  agent {
    docker {
      image SBT_IMAGE_TAG
      label 'test'
      reuseNode true
      args '-u sbtuser -v $HOME/.ivy2:/home/sbtuser/.ivy2/'
    }
  }
  steps {
    sh "sbt -no-colors ${sbtPRtargets}"
  }
}

If I replace the args with args '-u root --privileged -v $HOME/.ivy2:/home/sbtuser/.ivy2/' the sbt commands run fine.
How can I make the stage work in non-privileged mode or using sbtuser?
